# Search Enigne Functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make a small search engine from an assignment. I tried playing around with it, but Im stuck. I need to hide all 50 results at the beginning, then when the person starts searching the results narrow. Ive been stuck on this for awhile and tried googling some answers but havent really gotten anything solid

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="A5.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="navbar">
            <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-link"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Currency Exchange</a>
                <a href="#">Service 3</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-link"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-flag"></i> Contactez-nous</a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-flag"></i> Contacta con nosotros</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
        </div>
        
        <p>Welcome to the DesmoSearch!</p>

        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction" placeholder="Search for places...">

        <ul id="myUL">
            <li><a href="#">Argentina</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Austria</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bolivia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Brazil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Chile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Colombia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Denmark</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">England</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Finland</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gabon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Germany</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Greece</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Iceland</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Italy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Japan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jordan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kenya</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Kuwait</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Laos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Latvia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Libya</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Madagascar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mali</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Monaco</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Morocco</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nepal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">New Zealand</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Nigeria</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">North Korea</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Norway</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pakistan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Panama</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Paraguay</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Peru</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Poland</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portugal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">San Marino</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">South Africa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">South Korea</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Spain</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sweden</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Thailand</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Turkey</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tuvalu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Uganda</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">United States</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Uruguay</a></li>
            
        </ul>
        <script src="" async defer>

            function myFunction(){
                var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
                input = document.getElementById('myInput');
                filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
                li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

                for(i=0; i< li.length; i++){
                    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
                    if(txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) >-1){
                        li[i].style.display = "";
                    }else{
                        li[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>


    .navbar {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #555;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .navbar a {
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 12px;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .navbar a:hover {
        background-color: #000;
    }
    
    .active {
        background-color: #04AA6D;
    }
    
    .dropdown-link {
        background-color: #04AA6D;
        color:white;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-link {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
    
    #myInput {
        background-image: url('https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/search?style=solid');
        background-position: 10px 12px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    #myUL {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    #myUL li a {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        margin-top: -1px;
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        padding: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: black;
        display: block;
    }
    
    #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width:500px){
        .navbar a {
            float: none;
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I run your application and fixed some minor errors.

1. Calling "myFunction()"
2. Removing the `src=""` from the `<script>` tag

You could run the code below to see your application in action.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="A5.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .navbar {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #555;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        
        .navbar a {
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 12px;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
        }
        
        .navbar a:hover {
            background-color: #000;
        }
        
        .active {
            background-color: #04AA6D;
        }
        
        .dropdown-link {
            background-color: #04AA6D;
            color: white;
            padding: 16px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
        }
        
        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        
        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }
        
        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }
        
        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }
        
        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-link {
            background-color: #3e8e41;
        }
        
        #myInput {
            background-image: url('https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/search?style=solid');
            background-position: 10px 12px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            margin-bottom: 12px;
        }
        
        #myUL {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        
        #myUL li a {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            margin-top: -1px;
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            padding: 12px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: black;
            display: block;
        }
        
        #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
            background-color: #eee;
        }
        
        @media screen and (max-width:500px) {
            .navbar a {
                float: none;
                display: block;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="navbar">
        <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-link"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Currency Exchange</a>
                <a href="#">Service 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-link"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-flag"></i> Contactez-nous</a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-flag"></i> Contacta con nosotros</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
        </div>

        <p>Welcome to the DesmoSearch!</p>

        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for places...">

        <ul id="myUL">
            <li><a href="#">Argentina</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Austria</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bolivia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Brazil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Chile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Colombia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Denmark</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">England</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Finland</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gabon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Germany</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Greece</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Iceland</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Italy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Japan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jordan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kenya</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Kuwait</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Laos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Latvia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Libya</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Madagascar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mali</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Monaco</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Morocco</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nepal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">New Zealand</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Nigeria</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">North Korea</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Norway</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pakistan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Panama</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Paraguay</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Peru</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Poland</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portugal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">San Marino</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">South Africa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">South Korea</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Spain</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sweden</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Thailand</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Turkey</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tuvalu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Uganda</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">United States</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Uruguay</a></li>

        </ul>

        <script async defer>
            function myFunction() {
                var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
                input = document.getElementById("myInput");
                filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
                li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
                for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        li[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        li[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }

            }
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```